# how to add a watermark to my command ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need help with this ffmpeg command

This command joins 2 video paste a subtitle to the second video and then takes the video in 2 qualities (720, 360)

I need to add a watermark to the second entry.

```
D:\electron\brenda\node_modules\ffmpeg-static\bin\win32\x64\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\entrada\intros/intro_720.mp4 -i C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\entrada\videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex [1:v]subtitles=tmp/Heartstrings_1.ass[v1]; [0:v] [0:a] [v1] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; [v]scale=1280:720[v2] -map [v2] -map [a] -y C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\salida/720_videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex [1:v]subtitles=tmp/Heartstrings_1.ass[v1]; [0:v] [0:a] [v1] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; [v]scale=640:360[v2] -map [v2] -map [a] -y C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\salida/360_videoplayback.mp4
```

I need help, I've been with this for hours

Comment: By "second video" do you mean the second input `intro_720.mp4` or the second output `360_videoplayback.mp4`?

Comment: I mean the second entry, sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "second entry", I assume you mean the second input. If so,

`ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\entrada\intros/intro_720.mp4 -i C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\entrada\videoplayback.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex [1:v]subtitles=tmp/Heartstrings_1.ass[v1];[v1][2]overlay=x=0:y=0[v1]; [0:v] [0:a] [v1] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; [v]split=2[v720][v360];[v720]scale=1280:720[v720];[v360]scale=640:360[v360];[a]asplit=2[a1][a2] -map [v720] -map [a1] C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\salida/720_videoplayback.mp4 -map [v360] -map [a2] C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\salida/360_videoplayback.mp4`